# Ajax File Upload Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a form with an input file and need to upload the file asynchronously to Django, but is not working with ajax. The code is as follows:

Form:

```
<form id="upload" method="post" action="/upload/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="test" id="test'>
<button  type="submit">Upload</button></form>
```

JS:

```
function upload(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('upload',$('#test').prop('files')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
    return false;
}

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(upload);
});
```

Django:

```
def upload(request):
    print(request.FILES)
```

Django returns:

```
<MultiValueDict: {}>
```

Console JS:

```
console.log(data.get('upload'));
File { name: "test.csv", lastModified: 1446743198000, lastModifiedDate: Date 2015-11-05T17:06:38.000Z, size: 14, type: "text/csv" }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the js console? If you set a breakpoint to `var data = ...` Can you see the actual file or is it undefined?

Comment: @fodma1 Returns FormData {}

Comment: with data.get('upload') I can see the file

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work by sending the form data to the same view. Honestly do not know what happened.